# Pivot Table directly from SQL using powershell

Tags: powershell, pivot-table

I am using a combination of powershell scripts I've found online (shown below) to create an Excel document with pivot tables. But, I've only found examples where the datasource for the pivot tables was data already-imported into the excel document via CSV, or other similar methods.  I can get those to work. But, my problem is that I would like to bypass the step of loading .csv data into excel and then creating the pivot tables...my whole issue is my dataset is way too large for excel...so I want to create the pivot table directly from a SQL connection.  I cannot figure out the right syntax to to set the datasource.  Below is my closest attempt...should  use "xlExternal" for the datasource? But how do I set the datasource then? Micorsoft's documentation/APIs are somwhat helpful, but their examples are all written in VB and they also use other methods I'm not even familiar with in VB, so I'm having a hard time translating the QueryTables.Add method and some others.

I believe the only 1 or 2 lines that I'm stuck on are this one:

```
$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$connectionString", $ws.Range("A1"), 
$SQL)
```

And/or this one:

```
$PivotTable = 
$wb.PivotCaches().Create($xlExternal,$selection,$xlPivotTableVersion10)
```

But my code gives the exception on this line:

```
$PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("R1C1","Tables1") | Out-Null
```

and the error is saying:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\NEWpsCode.ps1:107 char:1
+ $PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("R1C1","Tables1") | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

So, here is my code:

```
$DirectoryToSaveTo='C:\Users\me\Desktop\'
$Filename='myfile' 

$ServerName = "BLAH1"
$DatabaseName = "BLAH2"
$userName = "BLAH3"
$password = "BLAH4"

$connectionString = "Server = $ServerName; Database = $DatabaseName; User ID 
= $userName; Password = $password;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$connectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()

$xlCenter=-4108 
$xlTop=-4160 
$xlOpenXMLWorkbook=[int]51 

$SQL=@" 
SELECT Account1,Account2,Account3 from myTable
"@ 

$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application #open a new instance of Excel 
$excel.Visible = $True
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add() 
$currentWorksheet=1 
  if ($currentWorksheet-lt 4)  
  { 
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item($currentWorksheet) 
  } 
  else   
  { 
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Add() 
  }
 $currentWorksheet += 1 

$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$connectionString", $ws.Range("A1"), 
$SQL) 

$xlPivotTableVersion12     = 3
$xlPivotTableVersion10     = 1
$xlCount                 = -4112
$xlDescending             = 2
$xlDatabase                = 1
$xlExternal     = 2
$xlHidden                  = 0
$xlRowField                = 1
$xlColumnField             = 2
$xlPageField               = 3
$xlDataField               = 4    
$xlDirection        = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XLDirection]


$range1=$ws.range("A1")
$range1=$ws.range($range1,$range1.End($xlDirection::xlDown))
$range2=$ws.range("B1")
$range2=$ws.range($range2,$range2.End($xlDirection::xlDown))

$selection = $ws.range($range1, $range2)
$PivotTable = 
$wb.PivotCaches().Create($xlExternal,$selection,$xlPivotTableVersion10)
$PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("R1C1","Tables1") | Out-Null 


$filename = "$DirectoryToSaveTo$filename.xlsx"
if (test-path $filename ) { rm $filename } 
$wb.SaveAs($filename,  $xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
$wb.Saved = $True 
$wb.Close() 
$Excel.Quit() 
$wb = $Null 
$ws = $Null 
$Excel=$Null
```

So, if anyone can please direct me to setting up a pivot table using SQL connection directly, that would be extremely helpful! Even a very simple example will help immensely.

Comment: if you want to automate pivot tables generation by SQL source it might be better to use specialized BI tool for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the input! In fact I have started using Power BI to help address these issues.  I guess I was kind of re-inventing the wheel here, although I intend to some day figure out this solution.  If I do, I'll post my solution :)

Comment: as I know PowerBI pivot tables have some limitations in direct connection mode. BTW - I'm affiliated with products that also could be used for this purpose (you can found links in my profile).

Comment: Oh - great, thank you for the heads up and the pointer to your other resources!